# Parametrize the estimator of a feature selection step in a grid search?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

How can I parametrize the estimator of a feature selection step (here `n_estimators` of `RandomForestClassifier`) in a grid search?

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

sfm = SelectFromModel(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=42))

pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                       ('selector',  sfm),
                       ('regressor', lr)])

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

param_grid = {
    "selector__threshold": ['0.45*median',
                            '0.5*median',
                            '0.55*median',
                            '1*median',
                            '1.25*median',
                            '1.5*median',
                            '1.75*median',
                            '2*median'],
    "regressor__penalty": ['l2'],
    "regressor__C": [0.05, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.5],   
}

search = GridSearchCV(pipe,
                      param_grid,
                      n_jobs=-1,
                      refit=True,
                      verbose=3)

search.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 0):

This did it:

```
'selector__estimator__n_estimators': [10, 50, 100],
```